# Database for storing PCD files?

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I am working on Robot Object Detection and Identification project.
I am using kinect camera, ROS and Point Cloud Library for that.
Well my questions are

1] Which kind of databases are more suited to store PCD files?

2] Do we have to interface ROS and PCL for processing of ICP algorithm.

thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30385/database-for-storing-pcd-files??/) by [youga](https://answers.ros.org/users/1191/youga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2012-03-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Roboearth](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth) object recognition package is generating PCD files after recording the models and the user can upload this model to an online database provided by [roboearth](http://www.roboearth.org) which is containing different object models.

I think you can use this database!

---

Originally posted by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) with karma: 717 on 2012-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2